# Take too much time in get ajax large response data

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am calling a `GET` HTTP method for getting large amount of data. However, when the JSON response has a large amount of data, approximately ~100K object, then it will take too much time to send data to front end. I will get that data at backend within *15 sec* while that data in front end takes *2 mins*.

Comment: Well - then **don't send** that much data! Use some kind of paging or other mechanism to avoid having to send such a huge amount of data.

Comment: You can use Pagination watch this video it shows how to make a pagination using  asp.c# 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srN56uxw76s